# Use data from selected object in python scripting

Tags: python, scripting, select

In this picture I have a cube selected and in the transform panel you can see the cube's data, such as location and rotation. Is there a way to use the data of this selected object, like the x-location, and turn it into a variable?
[image]

Comment: Hello ! Here's all the available members of `bpy.types.Object`. Additionally I suggest you enable the developer extras in the preferences and the python tooltips which will open a tooltip with the property path when you hover over a field

Comment: That setting is just under Settings > Interface > Display > Python Tooltips nowadays. No need ot enable developer extras.

Comment: One way to do it are **drivers**.

Comment: ups forgot the link https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
If you change the x-location in the transform panel, the code will appear in the info  section:

bpy.context.object.location[0] = 1

So to get the data from the active object and turn it into variables, I did this:

xl = bpy.context.object.location[0]

yl = bpy.context.object.location[1]

zl = bpy.context.object.location[2]